# awk string inequality seemingly not working

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file where I want to find all lines where column three and four differ. My file looks like:

```
chr1:109506687  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
chr1:109506690  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
...
```

The code I use to find these lines is

```
awk '$3 != $4 {print $0}' Cardio-Metabo_Chip_11395247_A.txt | shuf -n 10
```

Problem is that using this command I get results like

```
rs3218791       [A/C]   TOP     TOP
```

Where column three and four are the same.

When I use the conditional for equality, namely `==` I get no output, which tells me that awk never considers the two columns $3 and $4 equal, despite them often being so.

Ps. using `:set list` in vim, my file looks like:

```
chr1:109506687^I[T/G]^IBOT^ITOP$
chr1:109506690^I[T/G]^IBOT^ITOP$
....
```

My awk version is GNU Awk 3.1.8, but I can't imagine that having to do much with anything. This should have been right in 1.0

What might be wrong?

Comment: I tried this on OSX (couldn't try the shuf -n 10 part), but the rs3218791 didn't appear when i ran the command. Is it possible it's matching the `^I`, that's all I can see that might be the reason.

Comment: Yeah, it might be that awk considers the tab and newline to be part of the column values, but that would be strange.

Comment: By default tab is also a separator like space so that is not the problem. Unfortunately I also cannot try `shuf` on OSX.

Comment: you could also try using `!~` or `~` in-place of `!=` to see what it does.

Comment: shuf isn't neccessary: it just outputs ten random lines, instead of head which outputs the ten first.

Comment: !~ ~ did the same thing as =, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using GNU Awk 3.1.8 on Gentoo. Are you sure you checked the false positives with `:set list`, not just the lines you pasted which are apparently OK?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: It is possible to convert your problem into an independent reproducible script on ideone.com

Comment: Adrian: I have checked that, and reproduced the error on other files of the same type. And also made simple test files where the error persists. Will try upgrading version next.

Comment: did you add a debug line inside your awk script like `print "$3="$3 "\t$4="$4`? Good luck.

Comment: Add `print "$3=<" $3 ">, $4=<" $4 ">"` and run it on 1 line that is causing you a problem. Pipe the output to `cat -v` to show any control chars. See anything?

Comment: @Ed Morton: Yes, thanks! There is a ^M at the end for some reason.

Comment: Besides logical errors on my part, most of the time awk doesn't trigger the way I want is because I copied a file from Windows to a Linux machine.  `^M` are common in Windows files.  What do `:setlocal bomb?` and `:setlocal ff?` show from Vim?  If you're using awk in a Linux environment, you want to see answers like `nobomb` and `fileformat=unix`.  If you don't see that you can use `:setlocal nobomb` and `:setlocal ff=unix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I can't reproduce your issue (see below), I think you're evaluating those values numerically rather than as strings (all nonempty strings —even `"0"`— numerically evaluate to `1`).  Try this:

```
awk '$3 != $4 "" {print $0}' test
```

That concatenates `$4` with an empty string and should therefore force your desired string comparison.

---

I failed to reproduce your problem with mawk 1.2 and gawk 4.0.1:

```
$ cat test
chr1:109506687  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
chr1:109506690  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
rs3218791       [A/C]   TOP     TOP
$ mawk '$3 != $4 {print $0}' test
chr1:109506687  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
chr1:109506690  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
$ gawk '$3 != $4 {print $0}' test
chr1:109506687  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
chr1:109506690  [T/G]   BOT     TOP
```

The `shuf` pipe shouldn't have anything to do with it, nor should tabs vs spaces.  (Though to be safe, I tried all combinations in my test.)

Fun tip:  `{print $0}` is implied if there's only one clause with no action. Therefore, `awk '$3 != $4'` is the same as `awk '$3 != $4 {print $0}'` ... though be sure you're not making code harder for your peers to read.